# Connect 2 MasterData In FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

We have 2 TFrxMasterData In FastReport
For example

```
In MasterData1: Product1 - Product2 - Product3

In MasterData2: SerialNumber1 - SerialNumber2 - SerialNumber3
```

I want to connect MasterData1 and MasterData2 to each other so that, for example

```
Print result = 
Product1
Product2------ SerialNumber2
Product3------ SerialNumber3
```

OR

```
Print result = 
Product1------ SerialNumber1
Product2
Product3------ SerialNumber3
```

That is, for each product that the serial is defined.
What is your way?

Comment: This is exactly what the MasterSource and MasterFields properties are for on TDataSet. What part of using them are you having difficulties with?

Comment: @KenWhite I have no problem. I'm doing something